# Parsing http response with 2 status codes

Tags: python, parsing, httpresponse

I want to parse http response and get all the status codes.

Command used

```
 curl -i -X PUT -T test1.txt http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/test.txt?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020&overwrite=false?op=CREATE
```

Below is the response I'm trying to parse

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 173
Connection: close
```

Here is the code I'm using

```
rom httplib import HTTPResponse
from StringIO import StringIO

http_response_str = """HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 173
Connection: close"""

class FakeSocket():
    def __init__(self, response_str):
        self._file = StringIO(response_str)
    def makefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._file

source = FakeSocket(http_response_str)
response = HTTPResponse(source)
response.begin()
print "status:", response.status
print "single header:", response.getheader('Content-Type')
print "content:", response.read(len(http_response_str))
```

This code gives me status code as : 101 but I need both the status codes in the response.
Can someone please suggest ?

Comment: Why does your response have 2 status codes?

Comment: I'm running a curl and it gives me two status codes , is there a way to skip it ?

Comment: It should only have 1, something is wrong somewhere

Comment: curl is working fine , now i want to parse http response from curl

Comment: Don't bother trying to parse this response that has 2 status code, instead try to fix the source of the problem that is causing the double status code

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I have kerberos enabled cluster and using curl command to access webhdfs. Can you give me pointer to start debugging this issue?

Comment: There are actually two requests, the first returns `100 Continue`, so `curl` obliges, performs a second request, and that one returns `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: how can I Parse it using Python or is there a way just to get HTTP status codes ?